# Restriction of vector field considered as derivation

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields over a manifold $M$ defined as a map from $M$ to $\bigcup_{p\in M}T_pM$. Suppose there exists a $p\in M$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $X$ and $Y$ agree on $U$.

There exists a linear isomorphism $\Phi:\{\text{vector fields on }M\}\rightarrow \{\text{derivations of }C^\infty(M)\}: X\mapsto (f\mapsto f_*(X))$.

I would like to work with $X$ and $Y$ as derivations, but I am unsure what exactly it means for them to agree on $U$ in terms of derivations. My first idea would be that if $X$ and $Y$ agree on $U$, then $\Phi(X)(f) = \Phi(Y)(f)$ if $f$ is defined only on $U$. But I fail to make this rigorous.

Comment: Instead of $f$ is defined only on $U$, you could use ${\text{supp}}(f)\in U$ that is to say $f$ has support in $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that $df_p(X(p)) = df_p(Y(p))$ for all $p\in U$ and $ f\in C^\infty(U)$ if and only if $X=Y$ on $U$.

The reverse direction is immediate since if $X(p) = Y(p)$ then $df_p(X(p)) = df_p(Y(p))$.

For the forward direction, locally we can write $X = \sum_{i=1}^na_iE_i$ and $Y = \sum_{i=1}^nb_iE_i$ where the $\{E_i\}$ are a local frame for the tangent spaces (you might need to shrink $U$ so that it fits inside a coordinate chart). Then, the condition $df_p(X(p)) = df_p(Y(p))$ implies that
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\,.
$$
So taking $f$ to be any of the coordinate functions $x_i$ gives $a_i=b_i$. Therefore $X=Y$ on $U$.